# How-to stop computer locking when lid closes?

Tags: laptop, power-management, lock-screen

Here are my power settings: [image: power settings]

How do I stop the computer locking when I close the lid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brightness & Lock has the option:[image: Other settings]